# Angularjs + ui-router: navigate according to the href, instead of the ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is there anyway to "force" the ui-router to visit a link according to its "href" attribute? 
I mean I have an anchor tag: `<a href="#mystate/89/10/items" ui-sref="my.category.subcategory.items({sub_category_id: 10})">Link</a>`. When I click on it, I don't know what's happening behind the scenes and how exactly the router works, but I get an error that some `$stateParams` are missing. On the other hand, when opening this link in a new tab, everything goes as expected. That's why I want to find a way to "ignore" the sref and make the link behave like it's opened in a new tab.

Comment: You can't put href and ui-sref together, one or the other not both. Then it should be useful to see your routes config.

Answer (score 2):

What happens behind the scenes is that ui-router creates `href` based on your state which you passed via `ui-sref`. Do not use both `href` and `ui-sref` on your `<a>`. If you want to **ignore** the sref, then simply remove it from the code.

Regarding the error, `$stateParams` is missing, do share the controller code. Apparently, your controller expects some params, which I assume is `sub_category_id: 10` based on `ui-sref` params.

Comment: I don't use them together. It's the generated "href". In my code there's only ui-sref.

Comment: Isn't the link created in `href` the same which you expect your `ui-sref` to create for you?

`ui-sref="my.category.subcategory.items({sub_category_id: 10})"` creates `href="#mystate/89/10/items"`. So, is this not the link you expect?

Comment: Actually it is the correct and expected link. But I loose the original  $stateParams in the way. It happens because I navigate to a state which is not nested in the `my.category.subcategory` state (while the `my.category.subcategory` state keeps displayed - thanks to the "sticky state" feature of the `ui-router extras plugin`) - That's why I want to use the href.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by `I loose the original $stateParams in the way`, but the destination state must have these stateParams, if it's part of the URL.